# What is the use of @ between two matrices

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, cnn, pytorch

I was looking into a repo, where I came across this snippet of code:

`priors = x[None, :, :, None, :] @ self.route_weights[:, None, :, :, :]`

It basically tried to incorporate weights of an input image matrix.
I am really not sure what is the use of @ out here and what are the advantages of using this. Is there any simple alternative too, like won't simple matrix multiplication work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/overview-basic-numpy-operations),  the matmul function implements the semantics of the @ operator introduced in Python 3.5 following PEP465.

Hence, rather than `np.matmul(a,b)`.

We can use `a @ b` instead.

Comment: The linked reference conflates ‘dot‘ and ‘matmul‘, but it is correct that it's equivalent to matmul & not ‘dot‘.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142485/difference-between-numpy-dot-and-python-3-5-matrix-multiplication

Comment: Thanks, that cleared my doubt